# How can I achieve long term activation of the lower back to improve my posture?

Tags: back

I have back problems and need to work on my posture, one element is the lower ab to 'pull' my lower back into a more upright position (I tend to fall into a hollow back).

When I ask about activation, I mean this: get the relevant muscles to stay tense and active for a long time after the workout so that my posture stays OK with less conscious effort. What is a training modality or exercise to achieve this effect?

I'm mostly looking at planks and kneeling ab-wheel rollouts as exercises that have, I think, a more max-strength focus for me but I also occasionally do exercises with a stronger strength-endurance focus.

Should I prioritize one over the other to achieve muscle activation?

([I've asked this on fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19556/best-way-to-achieve-muscle-activation-in-the-lower-abs) but it may be appropriate here, too)

Comment: Please don't post the same question on different Stack Exchange sites. This is probably a better fit for [fitness.se].

Comment: well, this site didn't exist when I asked on PF.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is a [weak correlation between posture and pain.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3611484/pdf/586_2001_Article_230.pdf)

Secondly, working on long term activation may hurt (as in pain) your back. 
If you find that a certain posture is good **for you** try to sets of time in which you are in that posture.

Remmember: your best posture is your next posture.

Comment: I still think that this needs some more explanation. The OP asked for more specific information than you give. Could you add in some more info?

Comment: 1) with me, the correlation between posture and pain is decent, the fact that it's weak overall des not help me much 2) the pain I'm worried about is a cinched nerve (not muscle soreness, that's ok), also I don't understand what you are telling me? (sitting relativly straight while meditating seemd to be good for me, do you mean something like this?)